# Is London's Greenwich park free?

Tags: budget, london

I'm planing a trip to see the Greenwich time line (Prime meridian). I did some research and found that Greenwich park in London is the place most visitors go to see this. Is this park free and is there any other place that I can see the Prime meridian?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The park is free. You can stand outside the gate and see the meridian, or pay 10 pounds to enter the observatory.  It's 9 quid if you book online.

More information: https://www.rmg.co.uk/plan-your-visit/tickets-prices

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79676/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-mayo-is-londons-greenwich-park-free).

Comment: To be clear, I presume “the gate” to which you are referring is that of the Royal Observatory which is itself well within the gates of the park itself?

Comment: @eggyal yep, sorry, right outside the observatory.

Answer (score 22):

For another place to see the meridian, you could go to Peacehaven, near Brighton. This is where the meridian meets the south coast of England.

The meridian is marked by a monument, at the top of the cliffs.
[image: Meridian Monument]
*Photo by Paul Farmer on Geograph, CC-BY-SA.* https://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/3810663

There is also a number of places in Peacehaven named after the meridian, including a park and a shopping centre

Comment: For completeness, the northernmost point of the Prime Meridian in the UK is a pleasant-looking stretch of beach east of Hull; there's a [marker on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/First+Point+of+the+Prime+Meridian+In+the+UK/@53.7597357,-0.0054243,15.7z/) but doesn't seem to be anything on the ground.

Comment: Interesting - I seem to remember a marker a bit further north at Flamborough Head, but the map suggests I'm imagining things. On the other side of the Humber estuary, there is a nice marker at http://lincolnshirecam.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-greenwich-meridian-line-cleethorpes.html

Comment: There is a peculiar road sign marking the point on the B1362 west of Withernsea. Peculiar because the sign is facing north whilst the road runs east to west so it is not visible to drivers.

Answer (score 17):

To add my two cents.
The Greenwich meridian line can also be seen in Cleethorpes, Lincolnshire represented by a stainless steel line cutting through a coastal footpath along with a granite globe and sign post. It is also free.

[image: Cleethorpes Meridian Line]

Comment: Can we get some kind of origin (and, if appropriate, licensing) statement for the photo, please?  I suspect it's your own work, but it'd be good to have it confirmed.

Comment: @MadHatter Seems to be [sourced from this site](http://lincolnshirecam.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-greenwich-meridian-line-cleethorpes.html).

Comment: Yes, I found that too, which is why I said I suspect it's the author's own work - but it'd be nice to have it confirmed, just to keep things tidy.

Comment: @MadHatter I'd prefer that we assume that users follow the law. If someone owns the copyright they can contact Stack Overflow. There's enough [copyright hysteria](https://www.theverge.com/2018/6/19/17480344/eu-european-union-parliament-copyright-article-13-upload-filter) going on in the world already...

Comment: @pipe fair enough, but especially at such times I think it makes sense to keep our own houses punctiliously in order.  I think we'll have to agree to differ on this issue.

Answer (score 12):

Just to add another place where you can see the Meridian line, the O2 Arena (formerly the Millenium Dome) is on the Greenwich Pennisula and has the line marked on the ground and a giant sundial that sits across in.

Answer (score 9):

You can go to East India DLR station.  When you go down to ground level (don't go over the footbridge), the meridian is marked and you can follow it to the Thames.